# allowing certain urls and deny the rest with robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I need to allow only some particular directories and deny the rest. It is my understanding that you should allow first then disallow the rest. Is this right what I have setup?

```
Allow: /word-lists/words-that-start-with/letter/z/
Allow: /word-lists/words-that-end-with/letter/z/
Disallow: /word-lists/words-that-start-with/letter/
Disallow: /word-lists/words-that-end-with/letter/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet looks OK, just don't forget to add a `User-Agent` at the top.

The order of the allow/disallow keywords doesn't matter currently, but it's up to the client to make the correct choice. See [Order of precedence for group-member records](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#order-of-precedence-for-group-member-records) section in our  Robots.txt documentation.

> [...] for allow and disallow directives, the most specific rule based on the length of the [path] entry will trump the less specific (shorter) rule.

The original [RFC](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt) does state that clients should evaluate rules in the order they're found, however I don't recall any crawler that would actually do that, instead they're playing on the safe side and follow the most restrictive rule.

> To evaluate if access to a URL is allowed, a robot must attempt to
>      match the paths in Allow and Disallow lines against the URL, in the
>      order they occur in the record. The first match found is used. If no
>      match is found, the default assumption is that the URL is allowed.

Comment: The order doesn't matter for Google or Bing, but it can matter for some other crawlers. It's better to put the allow first, to maximize the number of crawlers that will understand.

Comment: Can you name one crawler, please? I'm dealing with crawlers for 10 years and yet to see one that actually cares.

Comment: I admit I cannot find a live example, but the [1997 robots.txt draft specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt) says to obey the first rule in the file that applies to the URL being tested. This document is the first specification to introduce the allow directive, and the only semi-official one that I know of that is not specific to a particular search engine, so the chances that some programmer will choose to obey it are not zero. My real point is, it doesn't cost anything to always put the allows before the disallows, so why not maximize your chances?

Comment: Fair enough, updated the answer (and upvoted your comment). Cheers!

Comment: As stated, the order doesn't matter for Google (for sure) and perhaps Bing. No evidence for the latter, but at this URL Google sayd how their order of precedence works: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#order-of-precedence-for-group-member-records
So better having the allow first, or create a googlebot specific ruleset.